# Binomial Probability Distribution Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinations

Tom has $10$ crazy children. In honor of Christmas, he bought $7$ new toys for each one of them.

The children destroy a new toy within one day with a $0.7$ probability.

What is the chance that after one day **at least 8 children** destroyed **at least 6 toys each**?

Final Answer : $0.82$

I think the question is asking about Binomial Probability Distribution + little combinatorics. I don't know if that's right as well.

**Answer Attempt :**

I tried first calculating the probability that a child destroy at least $6$  toys , Let $X$ be random variable indicating that so :

$P(6\leq X) = P(X=6)+P(X=7)=\binom{7}{6}(0.7)^6(0.3)^1 + \binom{7}{7}(0.7)^7(0.3)^0 = 0.3294$

$ P(X<6) = 1-P(6\leq X) = 0.6706$

Now we need at least $8$ children to destroy at least $6$ , Let $Y$ be the number of children that destroy at least $6$ toys so :

$P(8 \leq Y) = P(Y=8)+P(Y=9)+P(Y=10) = $

$= \binom{10}{8}(0.3294)^8(0.6706)^2 + \binom{10}{9}(0.3294)^9(0.6706)^1 + \binom{10}{10}(0.3294)^{10}(0.6706)^0$

but I get really really small probability $(0.003)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  To obtain $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: Your reasoning looks sound to me.

Comment: indeed it seems correct to me too.